# C# Regex for validating words with no space, no special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have written the following Regex for matching only those words with no space and no special character. But it is matching with words containing space too. What is wrong in it?

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
if (!rgx.IsMatch(TextBox_EntityType.Text))
{
}
```

Comment: You can use "AJAXT:FilteredTextBoxExtender" for validate chars in your textbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the logic of your check so it does the opposite, and you take the appropriate action:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
# Match if there is something that is not alphanumeric

if (rgx.IsMatch(TextBox_EntityType.Text))
{
    # Do what should be done if the text contains non-alphanumeric
}
```

This one works just as well because [`.IsMatch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) looks for a match anywhere in a string (it tries its best to find a match), so either you make it match the whole string with anchors like Nikhil suggested, or invert the logic like I did (and which I believe should be slightly more efficient, but not benchmarked).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Added ^ and $.

The `^` matches the start of the string and `$` matches the end.

Comment: And also i have one doubt is this code `!rgx.IsMatch` correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: May be OP wants to do stuff when it does not match. You can also post that in the comments of question to bring in OP's attention.